# Storing and retrieving any shots of file extension in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am writing an asp.net web application that stores APPLICANTS data in a SQL Server database.
Applicant might post name, address, telephone and a file.

The file might be of any extension including `.docx` for resume, '`jpg`, `.pdf` for photos.
or even an Excel file.

Is it possible to store all these file extension on my database?

Or will that be lengthy?

Please help

Comment: **Yes, you can!** That should not be an problem at all - use a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column - it stores **any** kind of binary data, up to 2 GB for each column

Comment: Thank you for the help . how is the retrieval process? I mean how can i open the files?

Comment: You need to get back the binary data from the database in your code, and then either save that to disk, or do whatever you need to do to it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! Personally I would use FILESTREAM in your case and here's why

> In SQL Server, BLOBs can be standard varbinary(max) data that stores
>   the data in tables, or FILESTREAM varbinary(max) objects that store
>   the data in the file system. The size and use of the data determines
>   whether you should use database storage or file system storage. If the
>   following conditions are true, you should consider using FILESTREAM:
>
> - Objects that are being stored are, on average, larger than 1 MB.
> - Fast read access is important.
> - You are developing applications that use a middle tier for application logic.
>
> For smaller objects, storing varbinary(max) BLOBs
>   in the database often provides better streaming performance.

You can read up on FILESTREAM [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Also consider using it in conjunction with [FILETABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx).

Finally, here's a .net C# [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to read from FILESTREAM column.

Please note, FILESTREAM is available in SQL Server starting from 2008 version.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @user3057202 hi there, you didn't make any comments to my answer, just wonder if it was helpful to you? If not is there is anything I can do to help you with your question?